# How many gerunds are in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

"He made his own ink by *burning* charcoal and *using* cheap ordinary *packing* paper for *sketching*?

Comment: The four _ing_ forms that you italicised are all gerunds, according to traditional grammar.

Comment: 4, but they have different roles in the sentence